# Android - making the menu icons aligning themselves to the left instead of right

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I am using a Toolbar with:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Is there a way of aligning the icons on the left, next to the app icon instead of on the right?

[image: Toolbar screenshot]